# How can I collect geometries from a singlepart shapefile to a multipart using GeoPandas or other non-ArcPy solutions?

Tags: polygon, geopandas, multipart

I've tried to use the geopandas.collect.tool to do this using the snippet below, but it clears the fields from the input shapefiles and does not successfully collect geometries.
doc: https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.tools.collect.html

```
import geopandas as gp

gdf = gp.read_file('output/input.shp')
geos = gp.GeoSeries(gdf)
gp.tools.collect(geos)
gp.GeoSeries.to_file(geos, 'output.shp')
```

Can anyone correct my method or suggest a better solution?

Comment: Try explode: https://geopandas.org/reference.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explode. Then all your geometries can be accessed in your data frame.

Comment: Can you show the ideal example of before/after?

Comment: 'gp.tools.collect' method works directly with geometries of features instead of creating a new GeoSeries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code works as expected (where I used my own paths) directly collecting geometries of features instead of creating a new GeoSeries:

```
import geopandas as gp

gdf = gp.read_file('/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/polygon8.shp')
print(gdf)

geom = gdf['geometry']

new_geom = gp.tools.collect(geom)

df = {'id': [0], 'geometry': [new_geom]}

new_gdf = gp.GeoDataFrame(df, crs="EPSG:32612")

print(new_gdf)

new_gdf.to_file('/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/output.shp')
```

Used layer was a single part shapefile projected with EPSG:32612; as it can be observed in following image.

[image]

After running above code, loaded resulting layer is effectively a MultiPart MultiPolygon. It can also be corroborated with print statements used with **gdf** and **new_gdf** variables.

[image]

Comment: You're welcome.